# MySql 5.6 ubuntu linux no central panel

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have MySql Server + workbench (version 5.6) installed on a linux system.
I start it and I cannot see the home screen with the three colums: SQL Dev, Data Modeling and server administration. How can I activate this panel?
Instead I can only see : MySql Connections, Models and some shortcuts under a black coloured window.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it's not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting the old Workbench 5.2 interface, but that changed in Workbench 6.0. The following documentation shows the difference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-what-is-new-60.html

So, you should probably get used to the new layout. Create and open a MySQL connection, and then you'll see ways to both develop and administer MySQL.